# Как настроить component в joomla?

Tags: html, html5, joomla, cms, joomla3

Делаю свой шаблон Джумлы.
Есть такая проблема с выводом материалов

```html
 <body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <jdoc:include type="message" />
      <jdoc:include type="component" />
  </div>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

В материалах 3 статьи, которые должен вывести component.
По факту код получается такой

```html
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="system-message-container">
    </div>
    <div class="blog" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Blog">
      <div class="items-leading clearfix">
        <div class="leading-0" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
          <div class="page-header">
            <h2 itemprop="name">Новости</h2>
          </div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="leading-1" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
          <div class="page-header">
            <h2 itemprop="name">Тобыл</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="pull-left item-image">
            <img src="/images/images_news/tobyl.jpg" alt="" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">
          </div>
          <div class="article__item article__item_alignment_left article__item_html">Соответствующее решение будет принято на&nbsp;собрании местного сообщества 18&nbsp;марта этого года. Предложение по&nbsp;вопросу изменения статуса населённого пункта и&nbsp;переименования, по&nbsp;словам&nbsp;Б. Бекенова, поступило от&nbsp;инициативной
            группы жителей посёлка Затобольска в&nbsp;аппарат акима посёлка.
            <p class="readmore">
              <a class="btn" href="/index.php/smart-house/4-tobyl" itemprop="url" aria-label="Подробнее:  Тобыл"><span class="icon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>Подробнее...</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="leading-2" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h2 itemprop="name">Адвокат семьи погибшего Татишева</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left item-image">
              <img src="/images/images_news/image32657394_4a862eb5d53ed5882a9ad5cbd5cdc5c2.jpg" alt="Альтернативный текст" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">
            </div>
            <h1>Адвокат семьи погибшего Татишева сделал заявление по делу Токмади</h1>
            <h4>Через&nbsp;несколько дней станут известны результаты экспертиз, проведенных американскими криминалистами.</h4>
            <div class="article__item article__item_alignment_left article__item_html">
              <p>АСТАНА, 23 фев&nbsp;— Sputnik. Представитель семьи Татишевых выступил с&nbsp;заявлением по&nbsp;делу Муратхана Токмади.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article__item article__item_alignment_left article__item_html">
              <p>Адвокат Евгений Яворский сообщил, что&nbsp;к&nbsp;расследованию убийства банкира были привлечены американские криминалисты.</p>
              <p class="readmore">
                <a class="btn" href="/index.php/smart-car/3-advokat-semi-pogibshego-tatisheva" itemprop="url" aria-label="Подробнее:  Адвокат семьи погибшего Татишева"><span class="icon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>Подробнее...</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end items-leading -->
          <div class="cat-children">
            <div class="first">
              <h3 class="page-header item-title">
                <a href="/index.php/smart-house">категория 1</a>
              </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="last">
              <h3 class="page-header item-title">
                <a href="/index.php/smart-car">категория 2</a>
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="__disk_root__" style="position: static;">
  </div>
</body>
```

Как видно по факту футер уходит в материалы, и второй материал вложен в первый.
В стандартном шаблоне photostar наблюдается такая же проблема, а в шаблоне BEEZ3 блог отображается не в div, а в section, и разметка не нарушается.
Как бороться с этой проблемой?

Comment: А разве трудно проверить строение вёрстки ? у вас лишний </div> после <div id="system-message-container">. Этот закрывающий див должен быть в самом низу

Comment: Он вроде закрывает Message. А дальше начинается Component